# How to put a if this happens, then play this sound in HTML

Tags: html

How can I put an `if answered correctly play sound: "mp3 url"` in HTML?

I tried multiple ways, but they still don't work.

I am trying to do it with Tampermonkey

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible example of what you've tried and explain how it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You must use javascript for that. Try this:

```
if (correct) {
   var sound = new Audio('file.mp3');
   sound.play();
} else {
   var sound_i = new Audio('file2.mp3');
   sound_i.play();
}
```

Comment: @user15094555 I edited answer to support incorrect one

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Javascript to check if your condition returns true.

```
if(answeredcorrectly) {
    let mp3= new Audio('urltomp3file.mp3);
    mp3.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with just HTML, but with a little jQuery you can get it done.

```js
/* Create a sound element our function can reference */
const the_sound = new Audio("https://freesound.org/data/previews/555/555547_1676145-lq.mp3");
the_sound.pause();

/* Attach a handler to the form.quiz_form element and listen for the submit event */
$("form.quiz_form").submit(function(e) {

  /* Kill the form submit event */
  e.preventDefault();

  /* Get the selected form field */
  /* Note $(this) refers to the jquery element attached to this handler function (form.quiz_form) */
  let answer = $(this).find("input:checked").val();
  
  /* Check the value of the answer and continue if correct */
  if (answer === "correct") {

    /* Check if sound not already playing and play if paused */
    if (the_sound.paused) {  
      the_sound.play();
    }
    
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
Create a form with a set of questions. Each input element has a value of "correct" or "incorrect"
-->
<form class="quiz_form" action="#" method="post">
  <h3>This is the question</h3>
  <input type="radio" id="answer_1" name="quiz_answer" value="correct">
  <label for="answer_1">This is the correct answer</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="answer_2" name="quiz_answer" value="incorrect">
  <label for="answer_2">This is the wrong answer</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="answer_3" name="quiz_answer" value="incorrect">
  <label for="answer_3">This is the wrong answer</label>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit your answer</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's not my HTML code, so how would it work then? The website is aops.com/alcumus. I need to add sounds for correct and incorrect.

Comment: @user15094555 If you don't add your code and the point you are stuck at, how do you expect other users to guess it?